# Launching opera in new versions of selenium 4.4

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, opera, webdriver-manager

I am trying to launch opera browser in a newer version of selenium 4.4. But at the moment I could not find a solution. Is it possible to use WebDriverManager.operadriver().setup() to get a driver?

At the moment, the implementation is working with specifying the path to the drive

```
private WebDriver createOperaDriver() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "C:\\Users\\anser\\operadriver.exe");
    OperaOptions options = new OperaOptions();
    options.addArguments("-start-maximized");
    return new OperaDriver(options);
  }
```

But is there a solution to not specify the let before the driver, but use only WebDriverManager.operadriver().setup()?

if you do not specify the path to the file, I get an error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.opera.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases
```

Comment: See this for WDM  https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/1069#issuecomment-1625108546 . And this for Selenium4: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10835#issuecomment-1220128750 . This seems to be a 'new reality' for Selenium4 and Opera browser.

Comment: yes, I solved the problem, I used the latest version of wdm, it helped to downgrade the version of wdm 5.1.0 and selenium 4.0.0 and everything worked and when starting Opera you need to use chrome options 

`WebDriverManager.operadriver().setup();  
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();  
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");  
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");  
return new OperaDriver(options);`